# Syntaxis anomaly: array<object^>^ What does ^>^ mean?

Tags: syntax, c++-cli

During study Uart, I found this symbol ^ which immune to google.
Here code that I can not understand:

```
array<object^>^ objectArray = SerialPort::GetPortNames();
```

*https://youtu.be/cxgKTWTHX1w?t=304*

Comment: This is not C++, this is C++Cli.

Comment: The code is in Microsoft's proprietary language  C++/CLI (or whatever it's called this month), not C++.

Answer (score 0):

That's the [hat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160) operator (aka *handle to object* operator) and is applicable for Microsoft's `C++/CLI` and `C++/CX` C++ language *projections* which is used to denote

> that the declared object should be automatically deleted when the system
> determines that the object is no longer accessible.

It uses reference counting to keep track of when to be freed by the garbage collector.